# How to make table fields customizable for the end user

Tags: .net, database, database-design

I have 4 tables or entities:

1. Customer
2. Item
3. Contact
4. Transaction

I like to have a separate field for each table named **CODE**. This field will store the system-generated code for each table. But this system-generated-code has to be customizable by the end user. The end user must have the option to make up his/her own code as per his/her discretion.

How can i make this possible? Any clue?

Comment: I wonder if we can use METADATA in our database to achieve this solution. Would it be possible?

Comment: So, are you saying that the Customer table has a field (say) Customer-Code, and the Item table has a field (say) Item-Code, and that these are UN-related to each other? 

Do you have a table (say, called ITEM_CODE) that stores all the allowed codes that may be assigned to a record in the ITEM table?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a user-assignable CODE identifier, make it additional & separate to your ID primary-key field.

This gives you a reliable "internal identifier" on which to build the application, while preserving the ability for the business to assign some "business identifier".

Joining an integer ID "internal identifier" is also more efficient than a VARCHAR, which is what you'd need to give flexibility for the "business identifier".

```
create table CUSTOMER (
    ID          integer not null,
    CODE        varchar(32),
    -- other fields
    primary key (ID)
);
```

To be honest, you probably can't decide for the business how they wish to allocate CODEs -- so trying to use CODE as a primary key would render it impossible for your application to add rows to the table, because the rules to allocate these are too complex/ unknown/ not  delegatable to code in the application.

Really, CODEs should be for the business to decide -- not for you to try & second-guess, which would only ever result in your being wrong. PROD001, PROD002 sounds fine.. but then they'll decide to change the system for some different category of product. **You will never be able to correctly guess PAPERPROD0084/12/a, which the business will decide is what's correct, and so you will inevitable end up being wrong.**

Also, this lets you build a real application while the business scratches it's head & wastes time figuring out how the "business ID" system is going to work -- or changes it's mind.

One final tip:  allow CODE to be null, so people can fill it in later. Better to have it blank than incorrect.

Comment: I know that we cannot guess what sort of CODE field the user requires.  But at the end of the day, we can provide the end user an interface to enter all the required values to make up his/her own CODE.

Comment: Metadata can't do it. At the end of the day, the business rules & variability for allocating codes live outside the DB & application control -- the users & administrators have to assign them. You can index the column, but you can't make it `not null` or unique (unless your DB will allow UNIQUE to ignore any number of nulls). I don't see how metadata helps.

Comment: As you say, provide the user interface to enter/edit the CODE field, and show it all the search results. User will be happy.